# Htmx-indicator & Bulma css

Tags: html, css, sass, bulma, htmx

Bulma css natively offers an is-loading class that displays a spinning icon while the class is applied. https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/button/

Htmx offers an indicator attribute -- https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-indicator/ -- whereby it gives you a htmx-indicator class that uses opacity 0/1 while a network request is in flight.

I would like to use Bulma's is-loading class which modifies a button element vs the examples I find in htmx whereby the indicator attribute is used on some image/span element to display a spinner.

Essentially, as I understand it, I'm wondering if when the htmx-indicator class is applied to my button can the is-loading class by applied in tandem.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible. You need to install the loading-states htmx-extension like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org/dist/ext/loading-states.js"></script>
```

Put this in your body-tag:

```
hx-ext="loading-states"
```

If, for example, you want to load a modal on button-click your code should look like this:`

```
<button id="open-modal-button" hx-get="" hx-target="#modal" hx-trigger="click" hx-swap="innerHTML" class="button is-success" data-loading-target="#open-modal-button" data-loading-class="is-loading">Open Modal</button>
```

More info here: https://htmx.org/extensions/loading-states/

If you have more than one button, you can use "data-loading-path" to filter specific requests..